# Gosund smart switch

Tags: smart-switch

Gosund smart switch times out during connection process. Godsend  app shows connection to be 100% complete but then shows failure/timed out.

Comment: In order to answer this question - us "young bucks" will need some more information. What model is your switch and what frequency are you operating at? The frequency is important as wifi and regional electrical differences can play a role in intermittent failure.

Answer (score 0):

Watched the video about  switch. Do you have the propper wires in box? Switch needs a neutral to work. Black is power in ,red goes to load out.ground to ground or green wire. Put in wall turn on power try as switch lights should work,and green light should come on. Hold the switch till green light flashes.Then go to app store ,add switch and wifi codes ect, should work.